# Discord OAuth2 read user messages

Tags: c#, discord

I am successfully managing the user authentications and getting, for example, the guilds that user currently is joining.
I would like now to read the messages from a specific guild. For that, I am adding { `rpc, messages.read`} in the scope.

```
 HttpWebRequest webRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://discordapp.com/api/v8/channels/{here the channel id}/messages");
        webRequest2.Method = "Get";
        webRequest2.ContentLength = 0;
        webRequest2.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        webRequest2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

However, I am receiving a 401 Error because a non-Authorization.

If I add for example activities.read in the scope, that permission is requested to the user properly. However, I receive: http://localhost:65223/?`error=invalid_scope&error_description=The+requested+scope+is+invalid%2C+unknown%2C+or+malformed.`&state=...

Comment: Can you access other endpoints?

Comment: @mousetail, I can access to user guilds, but no access to pins, archive or any other endpoints.

Comment: what oauth permissions do you request?

Comment: identify, guilds, rpc, messages.read, activities.read

Comment: I am getting %2C malfomed url if I add activities.read for example. Updated the question